# Database Error while inserting

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have written the Database class & trying to insert the values in the database but i am getting Exception like this android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "15": syntax error: , while compiling:

```
insert into tbl_setmessage (Title,Message,DateFrom,StartTime,ExpiryDate,ExpiryTime)        values 
('Swapnil','hii','12-3-2012 '15:53'14-3-2012 '15:54')
```

what is the problem

My Databse class is

```
public class DataBaseCreator {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SetMessage.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;

public DataBaseCreator(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
    this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}


public long insert(String TABLE_NAME, String TABLE_FIELDS, String TABLE_VALUES) {
    String INSERT = "insert into " 
            + TABLE_NAME + "("+ TABLE_FIELDS +") values ("+TABLE_VALUES+")";
    this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
    return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
}
public void closeDb() {
    this.db.close();
}  

private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Set_message (Tittle VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL," +
     "Message VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,"+
        "Date_from DATETIME NOT NULL,"+
         "Start_Time DATETIME NOT NULL,"+
        "Expiry_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,"+
         "Expiry_Time DATETIME NOT NULL)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public void open() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and main class is

```
btn_SetMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            baseCreator.insert("tbl_setmessage ","Title,Message,DateFrom,StartTime,ExpiryDate,ExpiryTime","'"+tv1.getText()+"','"
                    +tv2.getText()+"','"+StartDate.getText()+"'"+StartTime.getText()+"'"+ExpiryDate.getText()+"'"+ExpiryTime.getText()+"'");
            Intent i=new Intent(SetMessage.this,SelectLocation.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
btn_SetMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        baseCreator.insert("tbl_setmessage ","Title,Message,DateFrom,StartTime,ExpiryDate,ExpiryTime","'"+tv1.getText()+"','"
                +tv2.getText()+"','"+StartDate.getText()+"','"+StartTime.getText()+"','"+ExpiryDate.getText()+"','"+ExpiryTime.getText()+"'");
        Intent i=new Intent(SetMessage.this,SelectLocation.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

You lost some " ',' "

Comment: I have tried this now giving exception like this Android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tbl_setmessage: , while compiling: insert into tbl_setmessage

Comment: Because it is Set_message (Your SQL is "CREATE TABLE Set_message (Tittle VARCHAR(30) ....")

Answer (score 0):

This is your error message, that I took the liberty of reformating:

> I have written the Database class & trying to insert the values in the database but i am getting Exception like this
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "15": syntax error: , while compiling: insert into tbl_setmessage (Title,Message,DateFrom,StartTime,ExpiryDate,ExpiryTime) values **('Swapnil','hii','12-3-2012 '15:53'14-3-2012 '15:54')**

As you can see in the bold part, some commas are missing. Try this:

```
insert into tbl_setmessage (Title,Message,DateFrom,StartTime,ExpiryDate,ExpiryTime) values ('Swapnil','hii','12-3-2012', '15:53', '14-3-2012', '15:54')
```

Careful also with your apostrophes (symbol `'`).

Also, why don't you use the [Android SQLite APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)? They're quite convenient. You can also use [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //decleration
  EventDataSQLHelper eventsData;// class where database is created
    SQLiteDatabase dbx ;
    SQLiteDatabase rdbx;
     ContentValues values;
//onCreate
 eventsData = new EventDataSQLHelper(NewWakeupProfile.this);

        dbx = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();    
        rdbx = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
        values=new ContentValues();
 values.put("columnname1",value1);  
 values.put("columnname1",value2);  
 values.put("columnname1",value3);  
 values.put("columnname1",value4);
.......
......
.......


//insert query
dbx.insert("tablename", null,values);
```